# Encoding Issue while reading Excel file through PHP COM

Tags: php, excel, encoding, utf-8, com-interop

I am reading an excel spreadsheet with PHP COM utility, everything is working fine except there are some cells in Excel file having different language data. When I read this data through PHP Com it displays like **???????**

```
$ExlApp = new COM ( "Excel.Application" );
$workbook = $ExlApp->Workbooks->Open ( 'f:\dev\htdocs\excel\testfile.xlsx' );
$worksheet = $workbook->worksheets ( 1 );

$done = false;
$row_index = 1;
while ( $done == false ) {

    $english = $worksheet->cells ( $row_index, 1 )->value;
    $dari = $worksheet->cells ( $row_index, 2 )->value;

    if ($english != '') {
        $row_index ++;
        echo "<div style='float:left;width:420px'>".$english."</div><div>".$dari."</div>";
    } else {
        $done = true;
    }
}

$workbook->close ();
```

I have checked page encoding and its set to UTF-8. When I open original excel file it shows correct text but when I read it from PHP COM the encoding is lost. Does anyone have solution to this problem.

**EDIT**

How I can ensure that the value given by excel **$worksheet->cells ( $row_index,2)->value** is in correct encoding OR is there any property in Excel which I can set through PHP COM so it return data in UTF-8?

I have checked the encoding of value returned by Excel cell through mb_detect_encoding function in PHP and it gives ASCII where as it must give UTF-16 or UTF-8. It appears that excel does  not give value in correct encoding.

Here is the Excel file I am reading with this script:
http://asimishaq.com/myfiles/testfile.xlsx

Note that the solution is required using PHP COM-INTEROP only.

Comment: that's not a php problem, per-se. you just need to ensure that whatever medium PHP is outputting into has been told what character set the data is in. e.g. if you're dumping out to a web-browser, you need an appropriate `Content-type` header/meta tag.

Comment: @marc-b How I can ensure that the value returned from $worksheet->cells ( $row_index, 1)->value is in correct encoding?

Comment: either use mb_convert() and its cousins to convert the utf data coming out of the spreadsheet into whatever charset the destination is expecting, or TELL the destination that "hey, I'm sending you utf-8"

Comment: @marc-b I have checked the encoding of value return from Excel using mb_detect_encoding and it is ASCII. It must be UTF-8 or 16 it means the sender ms Excel have some issue in encoding?

Comment: I would try to set the codepage used by COM in its constructor: see http://php.net/manual/en/class.com.php (try CP_UTF8)

Comment: May be will be better use PHPExcel for parse xlsx files?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As pointed out by @rc we need to specify codepage property in COM constructor to obtain data in correct encoding.

```
$ExlApp = new COM ( "Excel.Application", NULL, CP_UTF8 );
```

By changing the above line in script the data is displayed correctly.